# Angular 4/Ionic3 production build changes components classname

Tags: class, angular, build, typescript2.1, ionic3

When running a production build of my app I noticed that the classes names changed. For example, a page component called "Search" changed to "t". This breaks my app because I need to identify the component by It's name in some place.

How could I retrieve the real name of the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because --prod runs a uglifier which seems to be changing the names of the classes.

Solution: change the architecture of my app to not depend on the class name.